# Pinescript/Tradingview limited iterations

Tags: pine-script, trading

As follow the picture below the vertical lines stop after some time.
[image]

How to make it to process all the way to beginning of available data?

The code is below

```
//@version=4
study("script time lines", overlay=true)

LineLengthMult = 10
LineLength = 100

drawVerticalLine(offset, cor) =>
    line.new(bar_index[offset], low-LineLength, bar_index[offset], high+LineLength, color=cor, width=3)

yellow = color.new(color.yellow, 50)

if bar_index % 21 == 0
    drawVerticalLine(0, yellow)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are limited to 500 lines per script. Only the last ~50 are kept by default, to increase that number, use:

```
study("script time lines", overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)
```